# Token already imported on metamask not showing

Tags: metamask

I have an issue on my Metamask wallet from desktop.
I can't see a token already imported few days ago.
I tried to import again but now is says that the token was imported and is still not visible...

What can I do to see it ?

Comment: Did you try contacting Metamask help? It used to work fine. The only option I could see is to reinstall Metamask, or install in a different browser.

Comment: ok. Thank you !